# How to organize such route protection using Laravel Passport?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-passport

In my laravel project I use Laravel Passport **Password** and **Client Credentials** Grant Tokens.

**Client Credentials Grant Tokens**

The client credentials grant is suitable for machine-to-machine authentication. For example, you might use this grant in a scheduled job which is performing maintenance tasks over an API.

This grant type has middleware for verify client credentials.

**Middleware path**

```
Laravel\Passport\Http\Middleware\CheckClientCredentials
```

By registering this middleware in `app/Http/Kernel.php` we can protect our routes

```
use Laravel\Passport\Http\Middleware\CheckClientCredentials;

protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'client' => CheckClientCredentials::class,
];
```

**Example route protecting**

```
Route::get('/orders', function (Request $request) {
    ...
})->middleware('client');
```

We can get any grant type access tokens by requesting to: `http://your-app.com/oauth/token`

**Example**

```
$guzzle = new GuzzleHttp\Client;

$response = $guzzle->post('http://your-app.com/oauth/token', [
    'form_params' => [
        'grant_type' => 'client_credentials',
        'client_id' => 'client-id',
        'client_secret' => 'client-secret',
        'scope' => 'your-scope',
    ],
]);

return json_decode((string) $response->getBody(), true)['access_token'];
```

**Password Grant Tokens**

The OAuth2 password grant allows your other first-party clients, such as a mobile application, to obtain an access token using an e-mail address / username and password. This allows you to issue access tokens securely to your first-party clients without requiring your users to go through the entire OAuth2 authorization code redirect flow.

Whith **Password Grant Client** we can authorize our users and protect auhorized routes using `auth:api` middleware. For eccess authorized routes we must set token to request header to `access_token` field.

**Example route protecting**

```
Route::get('/orders', function (Request $request) {
    ...
})->middleware('auth:api');
```

Now when both grant types (**Password Grant Tokens** && **Client Credentials Grant Tokens**) need to access token from header field `access_token` how I can protect my routes?

**Something like this**

```
Route::get('/orders', function (Request $request) {
    ...
})->middleware(['client', 'auth:api']);
```

How to organize such protection using Laravel Passport when both middleware waiting token from one field **access_token** of header?

Comment: It's not 100% clear what you're asking. Please could you provide a little more detail.

Comment: Ok @Rwd Now I'll edit my question

Comment: @Rwd I've edit my question by adding more details

Comment: @Andread Hunter i think what you are looking for is (https://filljoyner.com/2017/03/01/how-to-use-client-credentials-grant-tokens-for-your-api-authorization-with-laravel-5-4s-passport/) where the author breaks up routes for _client credentials grant_ (client middleware) and _password grant_ (auth:api middleware). I have currently the same issue on how i can share the same resource for both middleware at the same time.

Comment: And that post helped to your? @xyfantis

Comment: @AndreasHunter Well that post helped me understand that i have to use different routes for middleware client and auth:api. I have concluded that it is not possible to have on the same resource route two different auth middleware, and it kind of makes sense if you think about it.

Comment: @AndreasHunter also check this comment out [https://github.com/laravel/passport/issues/898#issuecomment-485372599] which justifies that you cant use both of _client_ and _auth:api_ at the same time

Answer (score 0):

like this maybe ??

```
Route::middleware(['client', 'auth:api'])->group(function(){
            Route::get(....);
        });
```